# How to add a right margin to the Visual Studio Code editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to add a right margin to the Visual Studio Code editor?

I would like to set a margin of 80 characters, but can't find such option in the settings.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

According to the Visual Studio Code's user and workspace settings [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userandworkspace), you can add rulers which mark specified columns.

Search for "ruler" in Settings. Click on the link to edit the .json file. Add the property below for rule at 80 characters.

Example setting:

```
// Columns at which to show vertical rulers
"editor.rulers": [80],
```

Comment: Search for "ruler" in Settings. You still have to edit the file, but VSCode will give assistance.

Comment: Just got VS 2022, and my searching so far indicates that none of these facilities exist in it. There is no Preferences under File, for example. In Tools->Options, a search on "ruler" turns up only something under Web design. Has anyone had better luck?

Comment: @mojado, I installed the **Editor Guidelines** extension in Visual Studio 2022 to get this behavior https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PaulHarrington.EditorGuidelines

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in 2022.

Answer (score 35):

Navigation to follow

1. **File** -> **Preferences** -> **Settings**
2. Select the tab option: Applies to only => **'User'** or **'Workspace'**
3. **Search** for **'rulers'**
4. open the **setting.json** under **'rulers'**
5. add the line `"editor.rulers": [80]`

Version I'm using is 1.49.1

Comment: I found Preferences -> Settings under Code rather than under File.  I'm using VS Code 1.60.0

Comment: For me on Mac OS, Code > Settings > Settings. Alternatively `cmd` + `,`